# Tick or Spider INSIDE my house

Tags: bug-identification, ticks, dangerous-insects

[image]

Help! Is this a tick or spider? It’s on the wall INSIDE my house. I live in Westchester,NY. I’m new here, so I’m worried. TIA!

Comment: I'm not an arachnologist (both ticks and spiders are arachnids), but after doing some research, my **guess** is that your little friend there is a spider.  If the abdomen is bulging out, that increases my confidence a bit that your friend is a spider.

Comment: BTW, the markings on the abdomen, although subtle, are quite interesting.  You may also want to post the photo on https://spiderid.com (if you do, please post a link here too)

Comment: @endanti-semitichate thanks so much for weighing in and will do!

Comment: You're welcome.  Sorry I'm not an expert on the topic, but hopefully someone here or on spiderid.com will provide an expert opinion.  I'm very curious about those abdomen markings!

Comment: @endanti-semitichate https://spiderid.com/picture/193239/  Let’s see what we find out! :)

Comment: Please always include an indication of size.

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but there are likely lots of spiders in various places in your house.

Comment: @joncuster I love spiders. Was concerned it was a tick!

Comment: Glad to hear you like spiders!  I was beginning to get worried about the little girl.  If it had been a tick, the easiest way to evict it is to take a plastic cup, put it over the tick, slide a piece of paper under the cup and tick, thereby trapping the tick, and flip it ouside, into its natural habitat.   (You probably know this, but someone may not.)

Comment: Welcome to the Outdoors Stack Exchange. We get a lot of "tick/Spider" questions, so this is a duplicate, which we try to avoid, so it might get closed. I've commented above with a link to an answer I wrote last year that shows the body shapes of ticks and spiders. Hopefully you can compare and answer for yourself.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate I think you'll find that you get *Parasteatoda* or *Steatoda* as the genera, probably *Parasteatoda tepidariorum* is my guess.